Instalo un modulo y python no lo detecta
Instalé python 3.12 y no puedo importar la libreria sinricpro y ya la tengo instalada.
Esto me aparece en la consola:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\tutec\OneDrive\Desktop\proyecto-arduino-prender-luz\prueba\test_sinricpro.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sinricpro import SinricPro, SinricProConstants, Event ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sinricpro'

Y yo tengo sinricpro instalado. Adjunto captura de pantalla de la pip list


En principio solo estás importando mal, debería ser:
from sinric import SinricPro, SinricProConstants, Events

o importando bien pero pero usando la implementación equivocada de Python.
Existen dos paquetes de esta librería, uno para Micropython (micropython-sinricpro-sdk):

https://github.com/sinricpro/micropython-sinricpro-sdk/tree/main

y otra para CPython (python-sdk):

https://github.com/sinricpro/python-sdk/tree/master

que obviamente es la que tu tienes instalada a través de PyPi.
La forma de importar, el namespace principal del paquete, difiere. En el caso de micropython es sinricpro y se importaría:
from sinricpro import SinricPro

pero en el caso del paquete para CPython es sinric:
from sinric import SinricPro

Es posible que estés siguiendo algún tutorial o intentando ejecutar algún código destinado para micropython (típicamente usado en ESP32 por ejemplo) y no para CPython.

Parece que estás teniendo problemas para importar la librería sinricpro en tu script de Python, a pesar de que la tienes instalada. Esto podría deberse a diversos factores, como la versión de Python que estás utilizando, el entorno virtual en el que estás trabajando, o algún conflicto con otras librerías instaladas.
Te sugiero algunos pasos que puedes seguir para intentar solucionar el problema:

Verifica la versión de Python: Asegúrate de que estás utilizando la misma versión de Python (3.12 en tu caso) tanto para instalar la librería como para ejecutar tu script. Puedes verificar la versión de Python en tu sistema con el comando python --version.

Utiliza un entorno virtual: Es una buena práctica trabajar con entornos virtuales en Python para aislar las dependencias de cada proyecto. Crea un nuevo entorno virtual, actívalo y luego instala la librería sinricpro en ese entorno.

Reinstala la librería: A veces, los paquetes pueden instalarse de manera incorrecta. Intenta desinstalar la librería y luego reinstalarla:
'pip uninstall sinricpro'
'pip install sinricpro'

Verifica la ruta de instalación: Asegúrate de que la librería se haya instalado en la ruta correcta. Puedes verificar la ubicación de instalación ejecutando el siguiente comando:
'pip show sinricpro'
Esto te mostrará la ruta de instalación de la librería. Luego, verifica que esta ruta esté incluida en el sys.path de Python.


-Verifica posibles conflictos: Es posible que haya algún conflicto con otras librerías instaladas. Puedes intentar crear un nuevo entorno virtual limpio, instalar solo sinricpro y ejecutar tu script allí.

Actualiza pip y setuptools: A veces, los problemas de instalación pueden deberse a versiones desactualizadas de pip y setuptools. Puedes intentar actualizarlos con los siguientes comandos:
'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
'python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools'


Si después de seguir estos pasos aún no puedes importar la librería, te sugiero buscar en la documentación de sinricpro por si hay alguna solución específica para tu caso o reportar el problema al equipo de desarrollo de la librería.

Por si acaso: El uso de IA generativa en SOes está prohibido y por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable.
